# How to implement password recovery feature to the users registered through admin

Tags: asp.net, forgot-password

In my application the new users are registered by Admin. A temporary password will be sent and required to be changed after logging in for first time.
Now want to implement security question and answer feature so that user can retrieve their password .

Current web.config setting is

```
 <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="##" 
        connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"  applicationName="/" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" 
        requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
        maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
        minRequiredPasswordLength="8" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1"  />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Read through lot pf post on this topic.I have myaccount page in the application to reset the password ,Can i implement MembershipUser.ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer to make the user to choose their question and answer in the same page.And use password recovery control for forgotten password ??

Or any other suggestion

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used the method called "ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer "  under MembershipUser class. I used this to enter the security question and answer in the user's "My account " page  . 
And implemented Passwordrecovery control and used OnsendingEmail event to verify the answer when user click's "Forgot password" .

but now the problem is OnsendingEmail event is not firing